# Non-Linear Forms for all Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms, ideal-class-group

**Edit to open the question:**

It looks like there are quadratic froms, satisfying these conditions. So,
Is there any other form like quadratic form, for example, say cubic form or form of higher degree than 2 in general in the literature? What terminology used if such thing exists (so I  can search )?

**Previous Version:**

All primes greater than $2$ can be written either in the form of $4k+1$ or $4k-1$. Fermat had successfully classified primes of the form $x^2+y^2 , x^2+ 2y^2, \text{and} \; x^2 + 3y^2$. Can all primes be written either in the form of  $x^2+y^2 , x^2+ 2y^2, \text{or} \; x^2 + 3y^2$?

In general, is there a finite sets of non-trivial forms (quadratic or something else but non-linear, i.e.not like linear $an+b$ or trivial form $x^2+y$) which can be used to represent all primes?

Plz inform related topics, terminology, book, research paper in the comment, if exists.

Comment: There are plenty, but most aren't particularly insightful. For example, $x^2-y^2$ generates all primes, but that's just because $(x-y)(x+y)$ can always be made into a prime with $x=y+1$.

Comment: @DonThousand if $x^2-y^2$ is prime how can you factor it?

Comment: there is not going to be any finite set of positive definite quadratic forms that represents all primes. The three forms $$  x^2 + y^2 \; , \; \; x^2 + 2 y^2 \; , \; \; x^2 - 2 y^2 $$ do the job

Comment: @WillJagy what job you are advising me to do?

Comment: @Andrew it's a saying, not a literal job

Comment: Every prime has the form $x^2 + y$ but this is not especially useful or interesting. Can you clarify your question? What are you looking for?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks for your participation, the problem is, I don't know much about the topics so it is hard for me to specify, of course i am looking for non-trivial and non-linear forms, your example is a trivial one, so it would be helpful if you compile related information and post an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Search for _represent primes with quadratic form_ and perhaps _quadratic reciprocity_.

Comment: You can have a look here: https://www.amazon.com/Primes-Form-x2-ny2-Multiplication/dp/1118390180

Comment: @Andrew  my comment above gave three nontrivial quadratic forms. Every prime is represented by at least one of the three. The phrase "do the job" is colloquial English, indicating that the three forms suffice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan back from shopping. The one detail is that the OP is listing only positive forms, and those will not suffice in any finite set. Furthermore, the excellent book by Cox considers only positive forms as well. Dickson's little 1929 book would be easier reading, also does indefinite binaries: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075/page/n5/mode/2up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form $x^2 + y^2$  represents $2$ and all primes $p \equiv 1,5 \pmod 8$

The form $x^2 + 2y^2$  represents $2$ and all primes $p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8$

The form $x^2 -2 y^2$  represents $2$ and all primes $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$

Every prime is represented by at least one of the three quadratic forms.

The most suitable reference is Dickson's little 1929 book,

https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075/page/n5/mode/2up

Comment: @Andrew no. I suggest you put a related question on Meta. If you have had private email from a moderator, it should remain private. However, if you indicate your understanding that you are not allowed to post anything new owing to some aspect of the status of this question, perhaps a method for you to improve your situation will be described.

Comment: Also this link does not work: http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/ , do u have any other source?